# Create vars from host inventory

Tags: ansible, windows-firewall

I have below infrastructure (3 servers running windows 2016 server edition)  where master server runs a IIS service on port 80(example) and 2 agents need to connect to them. To allow the communication, I need to add windows firewall rules to whitelist the ip addresses

- one master server (mas)
- and two agent servers (agt)

The task which I need to execute through ansible is, I need to add the below firewall rule only on the master server and should not run on the agent hosts. How to run the below task only on the master server so that the ip address details of agent(agt) machines are used while configuring the firewall rules.

```
- hosts: mas, agt
  tasks:
    - name: Firewall Rule Modifications
      win_firewall_rule:
        name: "IIS port"
        localport: "80"
        direction: in
        action: allow
        remoteip: "{{ansible_ip_addresses[0]}}"
        protocol: "tcp"
        description: "Allow agents"
        enabled: yes
        state: present
```

Comment: please indent code sample properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a solution(with a vagrant test setup with centos 7) as mentioned below but I think there should be a simpler way to achieve this :-)

**Inventory File:**

```
[master]
mas

[agents]
agt1
agt2
```

**Playbook:**

```
- name: Configure Iptables
  hosts: all
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - name: create a file to store inventory IP's
      file:
        dest: /tmp/foo
        state: touch
        force: yes
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Register IP address
      shell: echo "{{ ansible_enp0s8.ipv4.address }}"
      register: op
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: write IP's to a temp file
      lineinfile:
        dest: /tmp/foo
        line: "{{ op.stdout_lines[0] }}"
        insertafter: EOF
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Add firewall rules
      iptables:
        chain: INPUT
        source: "{{item}}"
        protocol: tcp
        destination_port: 80
        jump: ACCEPT
      with_lines: cat /tmp/foo
      when: ansible_hostname == 'mas'
```